# Need to offset an element in React that is attached to a Three.js object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

The current offset method, `<Html position={[0, 0, 0.25]}>`, has the element stuttering when the scene is played. If I remove the `position={[0, 0, 0.25]}` it renders just fine. I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if I can provide any more info. I'm mostly using typescript